# Android SQLite and server database 2 way sync offline

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization

My database structure is: 
 [image]

I want to sync it both ways between my android `SQLite` and server using a `sync adapter`.

The android application can perform all `CRUD` operations and the website can do the same thing.

The `website` will use the `server` database. Currently I use `PostgreSQL` but it can be changed.

The `mobile app` will use its own `local` database.

How can I sync them? The big problem is with the `primary key`.

1. One of the ideas is to use `uuid` as primary keys but there are performance issues, because as you can see there are some join I need to perform to get from the user to other tables.
2. Another idea is to leave the `primary key` as `auto increment integers` and use `uuid` columns only for syncing. But this adds a new table column for each `primary` and `foreign key` in each table.
3. Last one is to use a `compound key` as primary. This one will include 3 columns `user_id`, `id` (origin database id) and `device_id` (website / mobile app etc). And the same thing for each foreign key.

Are there any better solutions ? If no which of mine solutions should I use ?

How does Gmail, Keep, Dropbox or other applications performs this kind of task?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: No. :( Happy to hear yours.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/) as it is much easier to work with data via JSON with the sync libraries already done. It is faster than MongoDB and it is a free alternative for Firebase also.